# what are differents between two fluent - CodeFirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, fluent

I have a `Category` Table , It's Recursive . it containns :

```
 public class Category
{
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Category Parent { get; set; }
    public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

I used below Fluent to setting that :

```
HasOptional(row => row.Parent).WithMany(row => row.Categories)
                              .HasForeignKey(row => row.ParentId)
                              .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

when I run Project getting this Error :

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Categories_dbo.Categories_ParentId' on table 'Categories' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

to Fix it I change Fluent with below :

```
 HasMany(row => row.Categories)
.WithOptional(row => row.Parent)
.HasForeignKey(row => row.ParentId);
```

and its work fine .

**what is different between two Fluent ?**

I think they are same , but I dont know why first Fluent doesnt work !